# bubble sort using pointer

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, bubble-sort, function-definition

I have written this code for Bubble Sort using Pointers, I'm not getting output.
Here is my code. Please fix this code. I am getting error basically in swapping syntax. Please help.

```
int sort_array(int n, int *a[]){
    for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= n - i - 1; j++) {
            if (*(a[i]) < *(a[j + 1])) {
                int temp = *(a[j]);
                *(a[j]) = *(a[j + 1]);
                *(a[j + 1]) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    long int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    sort_array(n, &a[n]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int *a[]` is already wrong; that's synonymous with `int **a` which is *not* what you're providing. (and your indexing in `main` and `sort_array` is invoking undefined behavior). You need to [turn up your warnings and treat *all* of them as errors](https://godbolt.org/z/e8qb1n7oY).

Comment: You know that array indexes are zero-based, but you seem to have forgotten that means the indexes end with one less than the size. So an array of `n` elements will have indexes from `0` to `n - 1`. If you use `n` as an index that will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And types matter. You have a `long int[]` in `main` but try to pass a  `long*` on to an `int**`

Comment: Do they not teach you how to use the keyboard's space bar? It's not worth trying to read code written this densely...

Answer (score 2):

The code is full of bugs.

You declared a variable length array

```
long int a[n];
```

with `n` elements of the type `long int`.

Thus in this loop

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
```

the index `i` equal to `n` will be a reason of accessing memory outside the defined array.

Also the conversion specification `%d` is used for objects of the type `int` instead of `long int`.

So the loop must look like

```
for(int i=0;i < n;i++){
    scanf("%ld",&a[i]);
}
```

Similar problems exist in this for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    printf("%d",a[i]);
}
```

that must be rewritten like

```
for(int i=0;i < n;i++){
    printf("%ld ",a[i]);
}
```

In this call

```
sort_array(n,&a[n]);
```

the second argument expression has the type `long int *` and points to a non-existent element of the array with the index equal to `n`. That is the pointer expression points outside the array.

On the other hand, the corresponding function parameter

```
int sort_array(int n,int *a[]){
```

in fact has the type `int **`. The compiler shall issue an error message that the argument expression can not be converted to the type of the parameter.

Also the function has the return type `int` but returns nothing.

The function should be declared like

```
void sort_array( long int a[], size_t n );
```

Due to this for loop

```
for(int i=1;i<=n-1;i++){
```

the function will not even try to sort an array containing two elements because this if statement

```
if(*(a[i])<*(a[j+1])){.
```

will look like

```
if(*(a[1])<*(a[1])){
```

In any case the if statement

```
if(*(a[i])<*(a[j+1])){
    int temp=*(a[j]);
    *(a[j])=*(a[j+1]);
    *(a[j+1])=temp;
}
```

does not make a sense. There are compared elements with indices `i` and `j + 1` but there are swapped elements with indices `j` and `j + 1`.

Thus the code shall be entirely rewritten. You shall do that yourself.

Comment: thanks for helping me 
i'm still learning about pointers, now i can understand my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all valid remarks by *Vlad from Moscow*:

- you should always test the return value of `scanf()` to detect missing or invalid input,
- `temp` must be defined with type `long int`,
- the test in the nested loop should be `if (a[j] > a[j + 1])`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort_array(long int a[], size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                long int temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    long int a[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%ld", &a[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    sort_array(a, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%ld ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```